What are the morning, afternoon and evening times for prayer?
As per scriptures, what are the morning (pratah kaal), afternoon (madhyahn kaal) and evening (sandhya kaal) times for prayers?
When do they begin and when do they end?
I am not asking for astrological muhurta times as to me following them does not make sense.
I want to read Vishnu Sahastranaam in the morning, but am not sure if it should be just before sunrise or after, and I’m curious about other periods.

We are jagrut (awake) during the day and not at night. So our bodies operate based on the Sun. Sandhya, is a shift from one to another, so our bodies do the same. Having said that, stotra parayanam has no bearing on Sandhya, unless that stotram/stuti has a phala stuti that describes the time for its recitation. For example Sankatanashana Stotram of Ganapti says "trisandhyam" meaning, its best recited thrice a day, one for each Sandhya. Another example is Kartikeya Karavalambham, and its phala stuti says "pratah" meaning post Sunrise.
Vishnu Sahasranamavali also has Phala Stuti but gives no bearing on time. However, Vishnu Sahasranamavali parayanam  can be done either as a japa or as a kirtana. Japa is internal emulation where as kirtana is external effluence.
Adi Shankara says "Prakrame Kim Japan muchyate Jantuh", so as per Yoga morning Brahmamuhurta is idle for Japa,tapa, dhyana, dharana and Samadhi. So the question to you is, are you planning for a japa or kirtana. Sunset Sandhya is idle for Kirtana.

Why do you keep posting answers without proper citation? "Adi Shankara says "Prakrame Kim Japan muchyate Jantuh"," where exactly???

Your all the citations are random blog posts which may not be acceptable sources.

@TheLittleNaruto "Vishnu Sahasranamavali Phala Stuti " itself is the reference. I cant give a book page number since most transmission is oral and family practice. However, I did a quick search for the quote you just referred in google and here is the link https://divyakataksham.wordpress.com/2017/12/31/sri-vishnu-sahasranamam-phalashruti-final-part/
So it was not a personal opinion or self framed sanskrit hymn. I did mention the quote and the person who said it. For the rest, i did give examples with Hymn names.

@SanatanaDhara I wanted the actual times/timeframes  scientifically. Does pratah kaal pooja have to be done after sunrise?

@RV10 prātaḥkāla associates to Daybreak. So its right before Sunrise but you can see the light and roughly between 3 to 5 am is associated to Lord Brahma (the creator) meaning the entire creation wakes up. that is why you see birds start singing and squirrels moving around. Respectively the Noon to Vishnu and Set to Shiva. That is why evening Sandhya with red sky is called Kaalagni Rudra. Scientific? Yoga believes in energy surge but there is no measure, and Sun being Pratyakṣa Divam (witnessable divine) we witness all its faces everyday with respect. Like the way people try to witness eclipse
